# Could you create a different url for each interaction that you did in script with jquery and ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

it turns out that I have a script inside an html that does several interactions but the url does not vary. My intention is that I vary to make it more googly for it.

Eg www.domain.com

** Note1 ** -> Script interacts with "btnCategoria" button. (www.domain.com/{category})

** Note2 ** -> Script interacts with "btn-select" button. (www.domain.com/{category}/{subcategory})

Currently, the script does the two interactions but the url remains the same (www.dominio.com). I have seen as option "window.history.pushState" but it would only give me a fictive url (www.dominio.com/{categoria}). My idea is that by subsequently placing the category or subcategory url, make the necessary interactions of the script to be in the desired position.

I leave the code of the script. Thank you very much for reading it.

```
  <script>
$('#contenedor-principal').hide();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btnCategoria").click(function () {
```

//Note1

```
    $("#cont-cabecera-filtro").animate({
                    top: $(".mh-layout").offset().top,
                }, 1600, function () {
                    // Animation complete.
                });
                $('#resultados').fadeOut(1500);
                $(".btnCategoria").removeClass("icono-texto-active");
                $.blockUI({
                    message: '<div class="loader">Loading...</div>',
                    timeout: 3000,
                    css: {
                        border: 'none',
                        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                        padding: 0,
                        margin: 0,
                        width: '30%',
                        top: '40%',
                        left: '35%',
                        textAlign: 'center',
                        cursor: 'wait'
                    },
                    //overlayCSS: {
                    //    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    //    opacity: 0.0,
                    //    cursor: 'wait',
                    //}
                });
                $(this).addClass("icono-texto-active");
                var id = $(this).children().attr("value");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://www.dominio.com/app_asp/Filtro?idcat=" + id,
                    type: 'GET',
                    timeout: 2000,
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#contenedor-principal').hide().html(data).fadeIn(1000);
                        $('html,body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $(".mh-top-header").offset().top
                        }, 1500);
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert("Ocurrio un error");
                    }
                }).done(function () {
                    var ventana_ancho = $(window).width();
                    if (ventana_ancho >= 350 && ventana_ancho < 575) {
                        var alto = $(".cont-cabecera-down").height() + 320;
                        $("#cont-cabecera-filtro").height(alto);
                        $("#divNuevo").height(alto);
                        $(".capa-video").height(alto);
                    } else {
                        var alto = $(".cont-cabecera-down").height() + 170;
                        $("#cont-cabecera-filtro").height(alto);
                        $("#divNuevo").height(alto);
                        $(".capa-video").height(alto);
                    }
                    $.unblockUI();
                });
                $('.texto-video').hide();
                $('.que-necesitas').hide();
                var imagen = $("#" + id).val();
                $('.capa-video').css("background-image", "url('/app-asp/Content/imagenes/" + imagen + "')");
                $('#bgvid').remove();
            });
            $(".btn-select").each(function (e) {

//Note2
                var value = $(this).find("ul li.selected").html();
                if (value != undefined) {
                    $(this).find(".btn-select-input").val(value);
                    $(this).find(".btn-select-value").html(value);
                }
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: Your code is not formatted as such in StackOverflow so it's hard to read. Notice that there is a "Code Sample" button in the editor that looks like this {}. Edit: Also, you haven't posted the full script.

Comment: Done, I have edited my post. Sorry.